# Angular/javascript show always 3 decimals in input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using angular and i want to show data to users with html input type="number"

```
<input type="number" step="0.001" class="form-control" style="width: 75px" ng-model="product.price"  />
```

I always want to show 3 decimal places. But The source where the data comes, has sometimes

```
value:1.01       -> i need 1.010
value:1.004      -> i need 1.004
value:1          -> i need 1.000
```

I've tried .toFixed(3), but this returns a string, which is not what i need( cant show that in input type number)

Tried to parseFloat(mynumber.toFixed(3)), but this will again remove the extra zeroes.

Maybe there's a way to mask the input, show some extra decimals if not present ?

Answer (score 1):

Angular filters do not work on input elements.  [Here](https://github.com/FCSAmerica/angular-fcsa-number) is an example of a directive that adds number formatting to an input using the ngModel $parsers and $formatters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `number` Angular filter for such a purpose: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

Comment: This works perfect. Howeever how can i use it with ng-model

Since, this wil work to display the numbers but, my scope will not update on change.

<input type="number" step="0.001" class="form-control" style="width: 75px"  value="{{product.price|number:3}}" price-Changed-Event  />

Comment: You're right. Not sure, perhaps can you use a `ng-value` field for initial display, in addition to the `ng-model` clause?

Comment: tried with :
ng-init="product.price=(product.price|number:3)"

Works if the input type is text, but i need to have it as number. user must be promted for num pad not the full keyboard as with text type.

Answer (score 0):

Still without an answer. As far as i've read it's a problem within the community, that the extra zeroes get removed , if input type=number.